# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable, xml to csv store

Tags: python, xml, csv

I try to extrac data from xml tags, my code displays an error at the level of the variable 'ref', yet it is initialized, i want to get sources for each tag in rows with the same id.

I add 'ref = (None, None)' before the loop but i got
Why ref got often error ?

```
 if index not in self.sources:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

```
SOURCES_REFS = []
SOURCES_DUPS = [ 0 ]
class Note(object):

    OLDS = { 'UNIQUE_KEY': 'key', 'CREATE_DATE': 'create_date', 'NOM': 'nom_note', 'AUTEUR'        : 'auteur', 'SRC' : 'sources',}

    FIELDS = list(OLDS.values())
    TAG = 'NOTE'
    def  __init__(self, separator=';'):
        self.separator = separator
```

it is at this level that I have a problem

```
    def start(self, e):
        if e.tag in self.OLDS.keys():
            attr = self.OLDS[e.tag]
            value = e.text.strip() if e.text else e.text
            if ( attr == 'create_date' or attr == 'modify_date' ):
                value = format_date(e.get('display'))
            elif attr == 'nom_note' or\
                attr == 'auteur':
                value = '|'.join(value.split('_RS_'))
            #loop arround sources whatever a number...
            elif attr == 'sources':
                value = None  
                #ref = {'source': None, 'reference': None }
                ref = (None, None)
                for child in e.iterdescendants():
                    if child.tag == 'SRC_MOT':
                        # UNIQUE_KEY                        
                        ref = (child.text, ref[1])
                        print(ref)
                    elif child.tag == 'S_REF':
                        refs = child.text.split(';')
                        for part in refs:
                            # remove surrounding spaces (trim)
                            r = part.strip()
                            # merge multiple spaces into one
                            r = ' '.join(r.split())
                            self.add_source_reference((ref[0], r))
            setattr(self, attr, value)
        return None
```

````
    def end(self, e):
        if e.tag == self.TAG:
            values = []
            for attr in self.FIELDS:
                value = getattr(self, attr, '') or ''
                values.append(value)
            csv = self.separator.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in values)
            self.reset()
            return csv
        return None

    def reset(self):
        for attr in self.FIELDS:
            if hasattr(self, attr):
                delattr(self, attr)

    def add_source_reference(self, ref):
        try:
            index = SOURCES_REFS.index(ref)
            SOURCES_DUPS[0] += 1
        except ValueError:  # first reference
            index = len(SOURCES_REFS)
            SOURCES_REFS.append(ref)
        try:
            if index not in self.sources:
                self.sources.append(index)
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(self, 'sources', [index, ])

```
````

Comment: `self.sources == None` is the problem. No different than trying to iterate over None: `[x for x in None]`

Comment: ok ! How can i fix that to get the resources in my csv..?

Answer (score 0):

In your `start` function, in the `elif attr == 'sources'` branch, you never change the value of the `value` variable, so you always `settatr(self, "sources", None)`.

Later (or before, I can't tell without more code, specially the `__init__` function and the full stacktrace), in your `elif attr == 'sources'` branch, you will enter the `elif child.tag == 'S_REF'` sub-branch, which calls `add_source_reference` that iterates over `self.sources`.

So maybe change your `__init__` code to `self.sources = []` if it is correct for you, otherwise your code is a bit complex to analyze, specially with many missing bits and no way to run it (and no data), so I can't make a better guess.